# Magento theme crash - Error 500 on theme images

Tags: magento, webserver

I successfully created a few magento themes, which are all running fine on the webservers. Because that there were some changes from other developers done on the webserver (also running fine) I tried to import all files from my theme back to my local system to apply some fewer changes.
After that my theme on the localhost crashed completely all of a sudden. The sources of the sites are ok, but all images, which should be loaded out of the skin/../images folder were not displayed. If i try to open them with my browser I got a 500 Internal Server Error, but they are stored on the right place in the file system.

So I checked a few of my earlier themes, but they were all fine, if i back up them from the file system or other folders to my magento installation.

So i finally set up a new local magento installation, but get the same Error as well. As I said, all my other themes are working well, and the webserver with the actual theme has no issues so far.

best regards

Edit to answer the idea of @Oğuz

Thank you for your answers.
I checked the logs after I get the error, and get the following:

```
[Sun Mar 18 20:53:24 2012] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/theme/media/catalog/category/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, referer: http://localhost/theme/index.php/apparel/shirts.html
[Sun Mar 18 20:53:25 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/var/www/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/theme/index.php/apparel/shirts.html
[Sun Mar 18 20:53:25 2012] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /var/www/theme/media/catalog/category/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, referer: http://localhost/theme/index.php/apparel/shirts.html
[Sun Mar 18 20:53:39 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/var/www/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/theme/index.php/apparel/shirts/zolof-the-rock-and-roll-destroyer-lol-cat-t-shirt.html
[Sun Mar 18 20:53:39 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/var/www/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/theme/index.php/apparel/shirts/zolof-the-rock-and-roll-destroyer-lol-cat-t-shirt.html
[Sun Mar 18 20:54:37 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/theme/app/etc/local.xml
[Sun Mar 18 20:54:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/var/www/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/theme/index.php/apparel/shirts/zolof-the-rock-and-roll-destroyer-lol-cat-t-shirt.html
[Sun Mar 18 20:54:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] script '/var/www/index.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/theme/index.php/apparel/shirts/zolof-the-rock-and-roll-destroyer-lol-cat-t-shirt.html
[Sun Mar 18 20:56:33 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/theme/app/etc/local.xml
[Sun Mar 18 20:56:41 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/theme/app/etc/local.xml
[Sun Mar 18 20:56:49 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /var/www/theme/skin/frontend/theme/green/images/.htaccess: Invalid command 'ExpiresDefault', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

I'm not sure, why I'm getting these all of a sudden. I try to focus on the local.xml issue first.

Edit #2

Thank you for all the ideas and answers. After checking my local server I discovered, that i have that issue on nearly every page hosted on my server. Seems to be a bad configuration somewhere in the apache configuration files.
I'll try to fix it there on my next step.

I also checked the AllowOverride directive as well, but it was already set to 'All'.

Comment: Have you checked the error log for the reason behind the 500 error?

Comment: 500 Internal Server is a general error message which is nobody knows what happened without to see code/environment of yours. Go to webserver log files and check what was going on there!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

add this line at the start of the file:

```
$_baseMedia = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseMediaPath();
```

then when you include the image instead of:

```
echo "<img src=".$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, "image_2")->resize(500, 500);.">";
```

add this:

```
if(is_file($_baseMedia.$_product->$getImage2())){
    echo "<img src=".$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, "image_2")->resize(500, 500);.">";
 }
```

This checks for broken images so magento wont throw an error if it cant find the image. Magento throws a fatal error if it cant find a image which is probably the reason for the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step, first try the followings ( should run in magento root directory) :

```
$ find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
$ find . -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
$ chmod o+w var var/.htaccess includes includes/config.php app/etc
$ chmod -R o+w media
$ chmod -R 777 /lib/PEAR
$ a2enmod expires
```

Open apache config file ( or .htaccess ) and change the following in `directory` directive which is your magento root directory.

```
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Like below :

```
<Directory /var/www/magento>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I just reinstalled the apache and solved all issues I had with the loading of my images. 
I could not specify the root of my problem, but the reinstall solved it for me.